# Localhost connect MySQL Docker confusion

Tags: mysql, docker

I created a `test_mysql` using the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name=test_mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123" mysql
```

I got the IP address using `docker inspect test_mysql`. The IP is `172.17.0.2`.

The strange thing is that when I tried to connect to mysql server on my local using

```
mysql -uroot -p123 -h 172.17.0.2 -P 3306
```

An error raised:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2' (51)
```

However, if I use the localhost IP address instead it did work:

```
mysql -uroot -p123 -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
```

My question is why I can't connect to the container use `docker inspect` result while `localhost` IP works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) while localhost IP works?
Let's see again your command to start container:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name=test_mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123" mysql
```

The  `-p 3306:3306` will "bind" the port 3306 of host to the port 3306 of the container. As a result, we can see that if there is any connections come to port 3306, they will be forwarded to the port of the container.
So, your connections on local IP will work:

```
mysql -uroot -p123 -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
```

See more detail on [Docker page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)

2) why I can't connect to the container use docker inspect result

It seems your container is connected to the default bridge network(docker0 may have IP:172.17.0.1 in your case ) which is often created by default when you install Docker.
You can find more detail in [Docker network page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network).Therefore, inside your container, you may "see" the bridge (you can try to use ping command", but from your local host, it may not know how to find/resolve the 172.17.0.2 and you got that error.